Why does CD reading repeatedly stop and start on Ubuntu Linux but not with MacOS
I have an external CD player, specifically an ASUS SDRW-08D1S-U. When I connect this to my Ubuntu Linux laptop and put in an audio CD, it is recognized and tracks are read in Sound Juicer.
When I try to rip the CD, it appears to work initially, but then I hear the CD drive start spinning, then stopping, then starting again, stopping... etc. The UI also hangs (i.e. shows no progress), and I can leave it for hours while no progress is made.
If I close sound juicer and try to use dd to make an ISO image, the read fails quickly without the spinning.
When I plug the hardware into a Macbook (a fairly old MacBook Pro, circa 2015), the drive works as I'd expect -- I can import the music using Apple Music, find the files, copy them over on a USB back to my Ubuntu laptop.
Is there some secret that I'm missing, perhaps some driver that I need to install? I'm a long-time Ubuntu user and dislike having to resort to the MacBook (which isn't even mine). Does MacOS somehow perhaps "workaround" faulty hardware and somehow make it work anyway, or what am I missing?
I'm thankful in advance for any help. I have tried searching the Internet for "ubuntu cd-rom issues" but I seem to only get results from the cdrom not mounting. In my case it does mount and appear to operate... until it doesn't.
Update: thanks for the comments up to this point. I did omit the dual-USB power supply detail, but I did in fact connect using the original cable and inserting both (male) USB ports into a powered USB hub, which in turn was connected to the computer. I also did attempt to connect the cd-rom directly to each computer and observed similar behavior as described -- in both cases, the layout of USB ports on the computers necessitated using only one USB and leaving the additional prong unconnected.
One thing I have not tried that now occurs to me to attempt is to connect the main USB directly to the computer, and the additional USB prong to the unconnected powered USB hub. I will try this and come back to leave a record for any future seekers.
The cd-rom is admittedly fairly old hardware and has no additional power supply, and it might be best to upgrade that in the end.

There is an insufficient amount of information for anything but a guess, but I would venture the Ubuntu machine is supplying 3.3V of power to the external drive rather than 5V. The Apple hardware is pretty good about consistently supplying 5V, but my Dell and Lenovo Ubuntu machines are hit and miss. It really depends on the icons next to the USB port. That said, if your external drive has a DC power port, using that to supply the power should resolve the issue.

A review of the ASUS SDRW-08D1S-U contains The SDRW-08D1S-U External DVD-RW Drive connects and powers via USB, and comes with a split USB connector with two ends to ensure that the unit is powered correctly. It may be possible to run the SDRW-08D1S-U from a single USB port if your system pumps enough power through it, but we'd suggest that was a bad idea, simply because if the power output wobbles a bit, your burnt discs could turn into coasters very quickly indeed. . Is it powered from a single USB port?
